# Docker Compose variable substitution from .env file

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose

I have following configuration:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
api:
    build: api
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}"
```

**.env**

```
API_PORT=4200
```

Both of these files are in the same directory. When I try to parse it with `docker-compose config` I get this message:

```
services.api.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

The thing is that it will work if I change the environment variable name to **APIPORT**, so that it won't have the underscore in it. Aren't underscores allowed in substituted variable name?

I've also tried it by including the variable through `environment` or `env-file` in docker-compose.yml and it hasn't worked.

Comment: Which version of `docker-compose` do you have? It works for me with `version 1.16.1`.

Comment: `1.17.0` and still not working.